# Why I use "Collectors.toList()" rather than "Collectors::toList" in Java 8 Lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, collectors, tolist

Usually after a `flatMap`, we use `collect(Collectors.toList())` to collect data and return a `List`.

But why can't I use `Collectors::toList` instead? I tried to use it, but got a compilation error.

I tried to search this, but cannot find any explanation.

Many thanks.

Comment: Collectors.toList() returns a Collector that can be used, it is not a collector.

Comment: @Niuhuru, can you post your code here. This will be helpful to debug the issue.

Comment: @matt I think the OP mean `Collectors.toList()` not `Collector.toList()` I think It was a typo

Comment: I guess the compiler would have given you a reason for the failure, some kind of type mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for you all's reply, my question has been solved. Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling the `<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)` method of the `Stream` interface. `Collectors.toList()` returns a `Collector<T, ?, List<T>>`, which matches the required type of the `collect` method's argument. Therefore `someStream.collect(Collectors.toList())` is correct.

On the other hand, the method reference `Collectors::toList` cannot fit as a parameter for the `collect` method, since a method reference can only be passed where a functional interface is required, and `Collector` is not a functional interface.

You could have passed `Collectors::toList` to a method that requires a `Supplier<Collector>`. Similarly, you can assign it to such a variable:

```
Supplier<Collector<Object,?,List<Object>>> supplierOfListCollector = Collectors::toList;
```

Comment: Too quick for me :)

Comment: Many thank for your answer, that answered my question

Answer (score 6):

Please see @Eran answer, as it is more detailed than mine, but If someone wants a **simple** explanation:

You can't change:

`collect(Collectors.toList())` to `collect(Collectors::toList)`

you can only change:

`collect(() -> Collectors.toList())` to `collect(Collectors::toList)`

Comment: Thanks for your simple answer, that's very useful for me.